# redux-saga: race between action and event channel

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I want to race between a redux action and an event channel using redux-saga.

```
export function * createEventChannel () {
    return eventChannel(emit => {
       MyModule.addEventListener(MyModule.MY_EVENT, emit)
       return () => { MyModule.removeEventListner(MyModule.MY_EVENT, emit)}
    })
}

....

function * raceWithActionAndEvent() {
   const channel = yield call(createEventChannel)

   // I want to race between Redux Action: 'MY_ACTION' and channel here 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
export function* raceWithActionAndEvent() {
    const channel = yield call(createEventChannel);
    const winner = yield race({
        channel: take(channel),
        action: take(MY_ACTION),
    });

    if (winner.action) {
         // then the action was dispatched first
    }
    if (winner.channel) {
        // then the channel emitted first
    }
}
```

In my opinion the code is quite readable.  You set up a `race` between two `take`s and act on whichever wins.

Please note,`createEventChannel` doesn't need to be a generator function (like you have in the original question)